# javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: AMQ219002: target address does not exist [condition = amqp:not-found]

Tags: java, qpid, activemq-artemis

I am sending a message to ActiveMQ Artemis's queue with Qpid protocol,if I use below codes that can success

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new JmsConnectionFactory("amqp://localhost:5672");
```

But when I use this way that will fail:

```
Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
factory = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
```

and below code is jndi.properties:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory
connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory=amqp://localhost:5672
queue.queue/myqueue=otd-aps
```

Could anyone help me resolve it? Thx!

Comment: The error in the title doesn't relate in any way to the code snippets you've given around connections, please clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.I had found the answer that I used a wrong queue name.The name should be jms.queue.otd-aps,this is a full name of queue.when using amqp to connect the queue , the name should be fully otherwise  not fully.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Queue or Topic that you are sending don't exist on server, and your client don't have permission of creation.